# POST value to json file (php)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I want to post a value from a dropdown list to a php file with JSON_encode using $_POST Ajax.

I tried this script :

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
      $('select.pam').change(function(){
          $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/charta.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data: { id_espece:$('select.pam').val()},
        success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              },
    });
          });
    });
```

and this is where I want to post it :

```
<?php   $id =  $_POST['id_espece'];
        $cars =  abv($id);
         print json_encode($cars);
```

But I get :

> Notice: Undefined variable: cars in C:\wamp64\www\charta.php on line
>   *39*

to be sure that the JSON file is correct I replaced `$_POST['id_espece']`  with a default value and it works , but whene I attached it to the select box I get the error .

Comment: What is `abv()`, did you mean `abs()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly You can have JSON encodings of scalars.

Comment: @Barmar Yes it does something but it does not create a valid JSONString, at least not in my test

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly The JSON specification has been expanded to include JSON strings that represent scalars, not just objects and arrays.

Comment: @RiggsFolly E.g. `JSON.parse("123")` returns `123`.

Comment: @Barmar Yea maybe, but `$cars = '123'; print json_encode($cars);` just outputs `123` which I believe is not a valid JSONString and not therefore a javascript object

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right. Then that becomes the string `"123"` when read on the client, and it parses to the number `123`. So the right thing happens.

Comment: @Barmar Even when `dataType:'json'`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. That just tells jQuery to automatically do `output = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: @Barmar Ok, thanks, another good day, I have reduced my ignorance level :)

Comment: Check your error log you should see `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function abv()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's not an undifined function, it's a function I used to ceat the connexion to the database . Anyway it's not the problem because Like I said whene I replace $_POST with a default value I got My Json Output ... Thank you for tour answers